# reledmac - no columns - different linenumbers in left and right margin

Tags: numbering, line-numbering, reledmac, lineno

I don't know if this is even possible but it never hurts to ask: I am transcribing [a medieval Dutch manuscript in which text is displayed in two columns](https://lib.ugent.be/viewer/archive.ugent.be%3A0D26B9D8-B058-11DF-BD99-004279F64438#?c=0&m=0&s=0&cv=153&r=0&xywh=1321%2C149%2C6227%2C3706). I have to display it in one continuous text. If possible, I would want to mimic this layout:

[image: the layout I want to mimic]

What's so special about this layout is the different line-numbering on the left and on the right. The left numbering counts the lines on 1 column of the original manuscript. The first line on "page 20r, column a" is 1, the last line on "page 20r, column a" is line 40. As you can see on 20rb (which is the second column) the numbering on the left is reset and starts again from 1.

The line-numbering on the right, however, is continuous and counts the amount of lines the whole fragment consist of. When starting a new text in the manuscript, that number would also be reset to 1.

---

**MWE**

I have a MWE with reledmac that mimics the left numbering (to a certain degree). There is just some slight problem with the linenumincrement, because it first counts to 5 and then numbers every 4th line (9 - 13 - 17)

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\linenumincrement{4}

\begin{document}

    \beginnumbering
    \pstart
    \ledleftnote{151r\textdegree{}a}\hidenumbering {\rmfamily \scshape some sneaky header}
        \lettrine[lines=3]{L}{o}rem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\\
        Donec sit amet diam vel sapien commodo tempor at at sem.\\
        Praesent mollis enim mauris. Integer eu consequat neque.\\
        Nullam hendrerit laoreet fringilla.\\
        Aenean massa dolor, tristique maximus aliquet vel, hendrerit non mi.\\
        Pellentesque euismod mattis lectus, vel pretium turpis condimentum efficitur.\\
        Ut commodo ante nec risus sagittis, vitae sodales massa dictum.\\
        Quisque scelerisque pretium faucibus.\\
        Duis gravida ex lorem, et tincidunt diam mattis quis.\\
        Aenean nibh elit, pretium id leo ornare, congue mollis est.\\
        Etiam dictum viverra libero in imperdiet.\\
        Integer vel scelerisque urna, et porttitor turpis.\\
        Mauris porta molestie tincidunt. Vivamus ut rutrum urna.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\\
        Donec sit amet diam vel sapien commodo tempor at at sem.\\
        the end
    \pend
    \endnumbering

\end{document}
```

[image: kinda MWE]

---

I have no idea how (like I said, if possible) to get the continious numbering on the right side. [I tried wrappring the whole chunck of text](https://pastebin.com/29cDbm5U) between a second linenumbering-package using `\usepackage[modulo,right]{lineno}` but that gets just ignored...

---

tl;dr

1. the numbering on the left in my MWE does something weird: it first counts to five and then displays every fourth line.
2. is it even possible to get a different (contentiously) kind of number on the right hand side?

Reledmac is kinda mandatory as I need to write a critical edition of the text...

---

Comment: do you need the second line number also in the critical footnote?

Comment: @Maïeul, according to the minuscule screenshot, critical footnotes are based on the left nummering: as in 'there is something you need to know on (20rb)13'